# Where do maven goals go?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I'm using Maven 3.0.3.  I want to write a simple task to copy a war file from my target directory to the Tomcat deploy directory.  Where do I put my goal?  I tried ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>socialmediaproxy</groupId>
  <artifactId>socialmediaproxy</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.1</version>

  <goal name="copy-war" description="Copies the war file to the webapps directory">
    <!-- This is Ant stuff -->
    <copy file="${basedir}/target/${artifactId}-${version}.war" tofile="${warDestinationDir}"/>
  </goal>
```

but when I run

```
mvn copy-war -P dev
```

I get this error ...

[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project socialmediaproxy:socialmediaproxy:0.1 (/Users/davea/Documents/workspace-sts-2.6.0.SR1/socialmediaproxy/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Malformed POM /Users/davea/Documents/workspace-sts-2.6.0.SR1/socialmediaproxy/pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'goal' (position: START_TAG seen ...y-war" description="Copies the war file to the webapps directory">... @9:84)  @ /Users/davea/Documents/workspace-sts-2.6.0.SR1/socialmediaproxy/pom.xml, line 9, column 84 -> [Help 2]

Any ideas? - Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ANT itself to copy the stuff from your target directory to the Tomcat Dir

- Since you want to move the files from the target dir, run the `ANTRUN` plugin in the package phase.

  ```
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.6</version>
  <phase>package</phase>
  <configuration>
      <target>
          <copy file="${basedir}/target/${artifactId}-${version}.war" tofile="${warDestinationDir}"/>
      </target>
  </configuration>
  <goals>
  <goal>run</goal>
  ```

This will run the ANT task mentioned in `<target>` after executing the plase goal.

Comment: Ant inside Maven should be a last resort, especially for something as trivial as a copy. Look for existing plugins which do the functionality you need and if not, resort to the antrun plugin.

Comment: Yes, usage of ant inside maven was not preffered. Please get a look to maven-resource-plugin or tomcat-maven-plugin. 
All plugins could be bind to a lifecyle phase in the pom via executions and configuration part of plugins in the build part of pom. So you can bind the resources plugin at install phase to execute the goal copy-resources: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html

Answer (score 3):

The goal part in the pom does not exist anymore, cause that's from Maven 1...but you defined a pom (model version 4.0.0) which is intended for Maven 3. Take a look into the current [reference for the pom](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html).